# Clojure's equlivalent to a jQuery Deferred?

Tags: jquery, clojure, promise, jquery-deferred

Clojure has `promise`, `future`, `delay`, etc. but none are semantically similar to a Deferred object in jQuery.  They generally block if dereferenced before the value is available.  Deferred objects utilize callbacks.  What does Clojure (not ClojureScript) itself offer that is similar to a jQuery Deferred?

Comment: Are you specifically looking for a semantic equivalent or solving some real issue with it?

Comment: Clojure supports promises out of the box https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/promise - they're in core.

Comment: The difference is in the terminology, a JS deferred is a clojure promise and a clojure future is a JS promise.

Comment: One thing to note here is Deferred's (and most of other jQuery stuff) are based on mutability. `deferred.then()` for instance; adding callbacks are side effects. You can surely build your own mutable data structures in Clojure. John Wiseman's answer is a start. Perhaps a deftype with a mutable list of callbacks and functions to chain commands just like Deferred... But that's not how Clojure generally approaches state.

Comment: This is closely related but targets cljs: http://www.niwi.be/2015/03/28/promises-and-clojurescript/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use other Clojure constructs to get what you're looking for, but I don't think there's anything in core Clojure that is similar.

As a simple example, this uses `future` but provides the computed value to a provided callback function:

```
(defn deferred [func cb]
  (future (let [v (func)]
            (cb v))))

;; (deferred #(do (Thread/sleep 1000) 7) #(println %))
```

You could add special exception handling, and use [`future-done?`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/future-done_q) to check whether a value is ready without blocking, and more.  (Callback-oriented approaches to asynchronous behavior are excellent in some circumstances, but if you haven't experimented much with the other approaches Clojure offers you might find them well-suited too.)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `core.async` is what you're looking for.
This is how I use it in ClojureScript(same for Clojure):

```
(defn get-db-data [href processf]
  (let [ret (chan)
        handler (comp #(put! ret %) processf)]
    (GET (str db-host href)
         {:with-credentials true
          :response-format (ajax/json-response-format {:keywords? true})
          :handler handler})
    ret))
```

This function immediately returns the *channel*, which (as I understood) looks quite suitable to be JS Promises counterpart.

Comment: A channel is much more than a single promise actually